# Will IIS be able to handle SSL with the new IIS Platform Handler?

Tags: iis, ssl, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

With latest updates the new IIS Platform Handler was introduced. And I am wondering, will I still be able to setup SSL in IIS as I was able before, or it will now have to be set up in Kestrel somehow? What can still be set up in IIS at all after this switch?
P.S. Similar question about gzipping e.g.

Comment: Why not test it out?

Comment: Well, I just hoped someone already had the experience.

Comment: You can setup SSL in IIS and IIS will forward the requests to it as far as I know.